# Matching on nested exception type

Tags: scala

I am using some client library and had some code that ignored a specific exception using `scala.util.control.Exception.ignoring`:

```
ignoring(classOf[ReallyNotThatExceptionalException]) {
  stuff()
}
```

Now that library changed to wrap all exceptionn in another exception class, which forced me to change my code to this:

```
try { stuff() }
catch {
  case e:WrapperException if e.getCause != null && e.getCause.isInstanceOf[ReallyNotThatExceptionalException] => { }
}
```

So what I'm looking for a more readable way to express "catch exceptions that are caused by".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

0__'s answer is good, but it would be better if you were not forced to write a specific object (`CausedByFoo`) for each potential exception.
As it happens, there is not much to change to end up with a generic `CausedBy` helper object:

```
class Foo(message: String) extends Exception(message)
class Bar(cause: Throwable) extends Exception(cause)

object CausedBy {
  def unapply(e: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = Option(e.getCause)
}

def test(block: => Unit): String = 
  try {
    block
    "ok"
  } catch {
    case CausedBy(ex: Foo) => "not ok: " + ex.getMessage
  }

test(println("hello"))
test(println("hello".toInt)) // uncaught exception
test(throw new Bar(new Foo("Ooops, foo error!"))) // caught
```

As should be obvious, you can use `CausedBy` with any exception (by example by doing `case CausedBy(ex: Baz)`.

You can even nest it to handle an exception caused by an exception caused by an exception (by doing something like `case CausedBy(CausedBy(ex: Foo))`

Comment: That looks like a clean implementation, thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 4):

The `catch` block can handle any regular pattern match, so

```
class Foo extends Exception
class Bar(cause: Exception) extends Exception(cause)

object CausedByFoo {
  def unapply(e: Exception): Boolean = e.getCause match {
    case _: Foo => true
    case _ => false
  }
}

def test(block: => Unit): String = 
  try {
    block
    "ok"
  } catch {
    case CausedByFoo() => "not ok"
  }

test(println("hello"))
test(println("hello".toInt)) // uncaught exception
test(throw new Bar(new Foo)) // caught
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked Régis' answer to allow matching against both outer and inner exception type.

```scala
trait CausedBy[T <: Throwable] {
  def unapply(e: T): Option[Throwable] = Option(e.getCause)
}

object IOExceptionCausedBy extends CausedBy[IOException]
```

Then you can match like this:

```scala
try {
  // do some DB thing
} catch {
  case IOExceptionCausedBy(exception: PSQLException) =>
    // handle PSQL exception
}
```